# Nmap couldn't show all ip address of devices which were connecting to the wifi

Tags: networking, server

I've use `nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/24` to detect which device using wifi too (assume that my IP address was **192.168.0.100**)
But the result only showed ip address of Gate way, and my IP address although my friend was using his android to play game on same wifi and other my friend was using laptop too.
How I could show all ip address of devices accessing to same wifi with me?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It depends on your WiFi router. It's functioning like a switch (send packets from Sender to Recipient), not a hub (send packets from Sender to all local nodes) It's not forwarding packets to the other nodes. Try specifying the broadcast address (`192.168.0.255`), or the individual nodes `192.168.0.{0..255}`.

Comment: @waltinator, I think that ```192.168.0.0/24``` same with your ```192.168.0.255``` and ```192.168.0.{0..255}```. Or maybe I think wrong? Could you give me full command line? Thank you.